# Only hide li elements on mobile, not tablet or desktop

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Given a footer using bootstrap and jquery to hide li lists only on mobile device, I need to be able to view the links when on tablet/desktop. With this current variation, the links are hidden on mobile, tablet and desktop. Setting the `display:none` property to `visible` works in chrome dev tools, but not sure the best way to target tablet and desktop to do this.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="footer-links">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 panel" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#about">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle">
            <i class="material-icons">&#xE145;</i>
            Link Head
          </a>
        </h4>
          <ul class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg collapse" id="about">
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 panel" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#why">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle">
            <i class="material-icons">&#xE145;</i>
            Link Head
          </a>
        </h4>
          <ul class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg collapse" id="why">
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 panel" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#quicklinks">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle">
            <i class="material-icons">&#xE145;</i>
            Link Head
          </a>
        </h4>
          <ul class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg collapse" id="quicklinks">
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-8">
          <h4 class="deal-text"><strong>A bit of ad text</strong>will go here</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
          <div class="footer-share">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/facebook_icon.png"></a>
            <a href=""><img src="/img/twitter_icon.png"></a>
            <a href=""><img src="/img/linkedin_icon.png"></a>
            <a href=""><img src="/img/youtube_icon.png"></a>
            <a href=""><img src="/img/google_icon.png"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(e){
  if ($(window).width() >= '480') {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
  else if($(window).width() <= '480'){
    $('.panel').on('click',function(){$('.collapse').collapse('hide');})
  }
});
```

**UPDATED JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/mxv9yq4m/10/**

**UPDATED WITH `visible-sm visible-md visible-lg` AND UPDATED JS TO DISABLE `data-toggle` ABOVE MOBILE DEVICE, BUT NOW THE PROBLEM IS HOW TO ENABLE THE CLICK EVENT WHEN ON MOBILE**

Comment: You can use media queries for this. See [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for a detailed explanation on how to use them.

Comment: Isn't that what the class "hidden-xs" is for in bootstrap?

Comment: I have tried both media queries, and using `hidden-xs`, with no luck.

Comment: I should be able to have the lists display by default, and set the click event to only trigger if the user is on a display under a certain width, but having trouble getting that working.

Answer (score 0):

So your goal is to collapse them to save space on mobile?

There's not an easy way to sniff for "mobile" that doesn't grab tablets because there's no clear definition of a phone versus a tablet from a technical standpoint. Think about it: there are 4k android phones and 1024px wide android tablets and they'll all give you essentially the same user agent string because they all use the android browser. Do you consider tablets to have a certain screen size in inches? What about phablets? Don't design with "phone" and "tablet" in mind, design instead for screen size. Hide the links if they don't fit, show them if they do. That's your end goal anyway, right?

What I would do if I were you is I would check the viewport width and height when the page loads, then if they're less than or greater than a certain number (which you'll determine by resizing your browser with your design open until it no longer fits), call the collapse method for all the panels. Because you're using Jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth < someNumber){
        //do your collapsing code here
    }
})
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with saving space. It's what the design of the page calls for. The divs have to be able to toggle on mobile, as you can see in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **bootstrap** that's hardly a problem.
Use visible-sm to only display links in tab and visible-lg for desktops.